# Unable to get the user's manager using Office365Users.ManagerV2() connector

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have 2 SharePoint People or Group fields which allow single selection. one field represents the User (DateCardValue6) and the other field represents the Manager. now inside the manager field I disabled the field & added this formula inside the `DefaultSelectedItems`, as follow:

[image]

But when I run the form and I select a value inside the User field, nothing will be shown inside the manager, any advice?

Although the user has a manager inside AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try settings `DefaultSelectedItems` property of manager data card to:

```
If(!IsBlank(DataCardValue6.Selected.Email), {
    '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
    Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & Office365Users.ManagerV2(DataCardValue6.Selected.Email).mail,
    DisplayName: Office365Users.ManagerV2(DataCardValue6.Selected.Email).displayName,
    Email: Office365Users.ManagerV2(DataCardValue6.Selected.Email).mail,
    JobTitle: "",
    Department: "",
    Picture: ""
});
```

OR simply:

```
If(!IsBlank(DataCardValue6.Selected.Email), {
    '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
    Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & Office365Users.ManagerV2(DataCardValue6.Selected.Email).mail,
    DisplayName: Office365Users.ManagerV2(DataCardValue6.Selected.Email).displayName,
    Email: Office365Users.ManagerV2(DataCardValue6.Selected.Email).mail
});
```

**References**:

1. [How to auto-populate the Manager Details based on the person field](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-auto-populate-the-Manager-Details-based-on-the-person/td-p/700190)
2. [Auto-populate person look-up as the manager of a nominated person (not current user)](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Auto-populate-person-look-up-as-the-manager-of-a-nominated/m-p/210845)